# Django Models: default callback: missing "self"

Tags: python, django, django-models

According to the docs, if you give a model field a callable as default, then this default method gets no parameters:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#default

```
def contact_default():
    return {"email": "to1@example.com"}

contact_info = JSONField("ContactInfo", default=contact_default)
```

I am missing the access to the other attributes of the instance. At best I would like to access `self`.

Use case:

```
class Face(models.Model):
    male=models.BooleanField()
    beard=models.NullBooleanField()
```

If the face is a not male, then `beard` should be set to False.

The default value should be applied only for new instances.

Comment: you might want to implement `pre_save()` signal instead.

Comment: Question: is it acceptable that some code creates a Face that is both `beard` and `not male`?

Comment: @spectras yes, it is acceptable that a face is both bear and not male. I just want to set the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use self in the function for defining default values. You would have to use pre_save signal for this.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Face)
def check_beard(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if not instance.id and not instance.male: # Check instance id if it saving for first time, and set default
        instance.beard = False
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: it's not possible to read the attributes of the model instance being created in the default function. `pre_save` signals will be run every time an instance is saved, so you don't want to do that either. There are ways around that, but signals make the code harder to read (IMHO).

What you might want to do is add a convenient method to the manager of the model manager.

```
class FaceManager(models.Manager):
    def create_person(male, beard=None):
        if not male and beard is None:
            return self.create(male=False, beard=False)
        else:
            return self.create(male=male, beard=beard)

class Face(models.Model):
    objects = FaceManager()
```

You can then create a non-bearded, non-female face:

```
Face.objects.create_person(male=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access self in default callback, because it is called on creating object and it can't be provided.

But you can override `__init__` or `save` method and check here values of your fields to make some changes. Make sure that in `__init__` you will make changes after calling `__init__` from parent class.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches you can choose from to interject and set the value of a model field that depends on another.

The suggested approach is to actually use [`Form.clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other). This would allow you to encapsulate business logic at it's the source.

Another approach would be to override [`Model.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects)  or register a handler for [`django.db.models.signals.pre_save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save), though these are usually reserved for overarching relational constraints and application requirements.

Unless your creating the models programmatically, without user input which would otherwise be drained through a `ModelForm`, you'll have to resort to one of the latter two. In most cases, the obvious approach is to satisfy such requirements through `Form.clean()`.

Comment: I guess Form.clean() and Model.save() are called always. I want a default value which gets only applied for new instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-smartfields](https://github.com/lehins/django-smartfields) for that:

```
from django.db import models 
from smartfields import fields
from smartfields.dependencies import Dependency

def has_beard(is_male, instance=instance, **kwargs):
    if not is_male:
        return False

class Face(models.Model):
    male=fields.BooleanField(dependencies=[
        Dependency(attname='beard', default=has_beard
    ])
    beard=models.NullBooleanField()
```

This will basically act as a `default` on the `beard` field, except you get access to `male` field value and a model instance. If you would like to have this sort of check every time `male` field is changed than you can extend `smartfields.processors.BaseProcessor` and pass it as a `processor` keyword argument to a `Dependency`.

In case your actual problem, you can do it this way:

```
def contact_default(value, instance=instance, **kwargs):
    return {"email": "to1@example.com"}

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ... other fields
    contact_info = fields.JSONField("ContactInfo", dependencies=[ 
        Dependency(default=contact_default)
    ])
```

So, in this example it's a self dependency, so whenever contact_info is `null` it will call the `default` function.

Answer (score 0):

I would override save.

```
def save(self):
    if self.male:
        self.beard = True
        super(Face, self).save()
```

Comment: Does this mean if self.male isn't true that save() never gets called?

Comment: I want a default value which only applies for you create the instance. Overriding save() would execute on every save.